# Python/selenium webscraping

Tags: python, selenium

[image]for link in data_links:
    driver.get(link)

```
review_dict = {}
# get the size of company
size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="EmpBasicInfo"]//span')
```

#location = ??? need to get this part as well.

## my concern:

I am trying to scrape a website. I am using selenium/python to scrape the "501 to 1000 employees" and "Biotech & Pharmaceuticals" from the span, but I am not able to extract the text element from the website using xpath.I have tried getText, get attribute everything. Please, help!

This is the output for each iteration:I am not getting the text value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. What text are you expecting to get? 2. Please post the code as text and not an image, it helps everyone who is trying to help.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I am trying to get "501 to 1000 employees" and "Biotech & Pharmaceuticals" from the span

Comment: If you know you want to get what is after `Size` label, it's not that hard using 
 bs4's `find()`

Comment: I am trying to use selenium all the way, since some of stuff that I want to scrape are in ajax.

Comment: You can still get the current page source with `html = driver.page_source`

Comment: what element has id="HeroHeaderModule"?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion.  That was meant for one of other items called location. I have updated it above but still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `//*[@class='infoEntity']/span[2]` , and then `.getText()`.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I have tried it before. It gave me this error:  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: Are you doing `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` and getting this error??

Comment: for link in data_links:
 driver.get(link)
 driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='class']") 
 review_dict = {}
 size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="EmpBasicInfo"]//div[3]/span')

Yes, unfortunately nothing is working.

Comment: What does `driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="EmpBasicInfo"]//div[@class='infoEntity']//span[2])` returns?

Comment: It gave me invalid xpath error. Thank you for trying.

Comment: I forgot the quotes to make it a string `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="EmpBasicInfo"]//div[@c‌​lass='infoEntity']//‌​span[2]")`. This works for me in a **[XPath Tester / Evaluator](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)**

Comment: I added the quotes before execution. didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want only the text, instead of interacting with some element, one solution is to use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html for you, with `selenium` getting the code built by JavaScript, you should first get the html content with `html = driver.page_source`, and then you can do something like:

```
html ='''
<div id="CompanyContainer">
<div id="EmpBasicInfo">
<div class="">
<div class="infoEntity"></div>
<div class="infoEntity">
<label>Industry</label>
<span class="value">Woodcliff</span>
</div>
<div class="infoEntity">
<label>Size</label>
<span class="value">501 to 1000 employees</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
'''  # Just a sample, since I don't have the actual page to interact with.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find("div", {"id":"EmpBasicInfo"}).findAll("div", {"class":"infoEntity"})[2].find("span").text
'501 to 1000 employees'
```

Or, of course, avoiding specific indexing and looking for the `<label>Size</label>`, it should be more readable:

```
>>> [a.span.text for a in soup.findAll("div", {"class":"infoEntity"}) if (a.label and a.label.text == 'Size')]
['501 to 1000 employees']
```

Using `selenium` you can do:

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='EmpBasicInfo']/div[1]/div/div[3]/span").text
'501 to 1000 employees'
```

Comment: I want to use selenium for the whole project instead of using soup. The website has some heavy ajax properties and I need to extract most of my information from that part. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply and your patience. I used your selenium version, it's working.

Comment: I'm glad to help! Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.